# How to pass query parameters to Ktor android

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, ktor

for fun return like :

```
fun call_api(){  
  client.get {
                url("url")
                parameter("1stParam", "2ndParam")
    
            }
}
```

where client is HttpClient

in code how to call it
callapi() ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`client.get()` returns an `HttpResponse`, which you can return from your function or keep in a variable

```
suspend fun getResponse(): HttpResponse {
     return client.get {
                    url("url")
                    parameter("key", "value")
            }
}
```

or

```
val response = client.get {
                        url("url")
                        parameter("key", "value")
                }
```

You can call either of the above, whichever you've used, inside a coroutine

```
fun callApi() = viewModelScope.launch {
    val data = getResponse().body<ClassNameToBeDeserializedTo>()
    // data contains your deserialized object
}
```